# Connection string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using connection string like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-8L8G5P8\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sai;User ID=sa);
```

But it raises the error at the server name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have messed up somethings .Try this.It may work

> SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-8L8G5P8\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sai;User ID=sa;");

you have messed double slash(\\) and double quote(" ")